# Regular Expression to C++ code

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to convert a regular expression (for passwords) to c++ code.

This is the regular expression:

```
(?=^.{6,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(){}\[\]=\+\-_:;"'`<,>.?\/|\\~]+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

The passwords should have at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one special character and one number. My c++ code however seems to allow passwords like "aaaaA1" which do not contain a special character. My code is as follows.

```
vector<string> StupidNonDynamicBrute(int Depth) {
vector<string> Words;
string Word = "";
regex Expression ("(?=^.{6,}$)(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*(){}\\[\\]=\\+\\-_:;\"\'`<,>.?\\/|\\~]+)(?![.\\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$");
ofstream Output;
Output.open("Output1.txt");
char Letters[] ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*(){}[]=+-_:;\"\'`<,>.?/|\\~";
for (int i = 0; i < 94; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 94; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 94; k++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 94; b++) {
                if (Depth > 4) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < 94; m++) {
                        for (int v = 0; v < 94; v++) {
                            Word = "";
                            Word += Letters[i];
                            Word += Letters[j];
                            Word += Letters[k];
                            Word += Letters[b];
                            Word += Letters[m];
                            Word += Letters[v];
                            if (regex_match(Word, Expression)) {
                                Words.push_back(Word);
                                Output << Word << endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Word = "";
                    Word += Letters[i];
                    Word += Letters[j];
                    Word += Letters[k];
                    Word += Letters[b];
                    Words.push_back(Word);
                    Output << Word << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return Words;
}
```

Some insight on the code: It generates all possible combinations of letters, numbers and symbols for length either 4 or 6 to use as a password. I also created a recursive dynamic function to do this ( for any password length) but it is extremely slow for some reason.

Comment: Why don't you just check those conditions explicitly?  (Rather than trying to cram them all into an unintelligible regex.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler to do that without a regular expression. Just check for characters that match the criteria:

```
static std::string specials = "!@#$";
bool validate(std::string str) {
    bool has_lowercase = false;
    bool has_uppercase = false;
    bool has_digit = false;
    bool has_special = false;
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while (pos < str.size()
        && !has_lowercase && !has_uppercase
        && !has_digit && !has_special) {
        if (is_lower(str[pos])
            has_lowercase = true;
        if (is_upper(str[pos])
            has_uppercase = true;
        if (is_digit(str[pos])
            has_digit = true;
        if (specials.find(str[pos]) != std::string::npos)
            has_special = true;
        ++pos;
    }
    return has_lowercase && has_uppercase && has_digit && has_special;
}
```

Comment: This way produces the exact same results as before. The first string it outputs is aaaaA1 so somehow it thinks it finds special characters.

Comment: The error  seems to be that it identifies all characters as special characters, with this special character pool :
static string Specials = "!@#$%^&*(){}[]=+-_:;\"\'`<,>.?/|\\~";

Comment: @ΑριστείδηςΑγγελόπουλος -- yup, typo in the code. I've fixed it. `std::string::find` returns the position where it found a match, or `std::string::npos) if no match is found.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely slow because you check for *a lot* of combinations (ie: 6<sup>94</sup> possibilities)...

Just check each conditions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    char c = input[i];
    if(isupper(c))
        containsUpper = true;
    if(islower(c))
        containsLower = true;
}

if (std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), (int(*)(int))std::isdigit) != input.end())
{
    containsDigit = true;
}

boost::regex re("[!@#$%^&*(){}\[\]=\+\-_:;"'`<,>.?\/|\\~]");
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
bool containsSpecials = boost::regex_search(input.begin(), input.end(), what, re, boost::match_default);

bool isPasswordValid = containsSpecials && containsLower && containsUpper && containsDigit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something more direct:

```
bool is_valid_password(std::string const& s)
{
    if(s.size() < 6)
        return false;

    // one uppercase
    if(std::find_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
        [](char c){ return std::isupper(c); }) == std::end(s))
            return false;

    // one lowercase
    if(std::find_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
        [](char c){ return std::islower(c); }) == std::end(s))
            return false;

    // one special
    if(std::find_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
        [](char c){ return std::ispunct(c); }) == std::end(s))
            return false;

    // one number
    if(std::find_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
        [](char c){ return std::isdigit(c); }) == std::end(s))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```